# I've removed a redirect from Next.config.js but it still is actively redirecting

Tags: next.js

Can someone explain to me why my next.config.js does not update on changes even after a rerun? And how I can get it to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Please apply `npm cache clean --force` & also remove `.next` dir and retry.

Comment: Didn't work, the issue persists still.

Answer (score 1):

Seems I had to clear the browser cache. Was first evident when I used another browser.
I believe the use of permanent:true caused this.